# Is it possible to use yolo3 with yolo9000 weights for more classes?

Tags: yolo, darknet

Right now I am using yolo3 but it does not have all 9000 classes.

Is it possible to use yolo3 with yolo9000 classes and weights?

I would like to have as many objects as possible to assign tags to some pictures and I am not sure if I should use yolo9000 or it is possible to use yolo3 with 9000 classes.

Update:
So, I tired loading the weights yolo9000 with yolo3 and the model does not find any objects. It seems I need to tweak something else.

Answer (score 1):

Got it, 
I needed to change thresholds when I call detect, default value is 0.5

https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/61c9d02ec461e30d55762ec7669d6a1d3c356fb2/python/darknet.py#L125

```
   det = darknet.detect(self._net, self._meta, im, thresh=.1, hier_thresh=.1, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Nice! I have a similar question -- how did you know what thresholds to set to?

Comment: Hi, I tried different options and choose one with the lowest false positive rate.  I did not mind to miss some objects but I had to be sure they are classified correctly.